# Sum the values in a tag in Datadog

Tags: datadog

I have a job that runs daily and it processes x amount of records for our database.  At the end of the job I'd like to send summarized data about what the job has done for instance.  I was thinking I could tag the metric with the following

successfully_processed = y
failed = z

The part I am struggling with is, how I would create a dashboard that can parse the tag values (x and y) so I can chart them coherently?